# Python: Drawing a Diagonal Line in Animation

Tags: python

I am trying to make an animation but I am not sure how to draw a diagonal line and move it.

```
import pygame
import sys

WINDOW=pygame.display.set_mode((800,300))
RED=(255,0,0)
WHITE=(255,255,255)
CRIMSON=(220,20,60)
BURGUNDY=(102,0,0)
CERULEAN=(153,255,255)
PINK=(255,102,102)


FPS=100
fpsClock=pygame.time.Clock()

x=0
pygame.display.set_caption("Animation")
while True:
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type=="QUIT":
            pygame.quit()
            sys.exit()
    #Animation
    WINDOW.fill(CERULEAN)
    x=x+1
    pygame.draw.circle(WINDOW, CRIMSON, (x,100),20)
    pygame.draw.circle(WINDOW, BURGUNDY, (x, 92),5)
    pygame.draw.line(WINDOW, PINK, (x,30),(x,70),3)

    pygame.display.update()
    fpsClock.tick(FPS)
```

The drawing is supposed to be a fish with a triangle as its tail. I originally tried to use the polygon function but wasn't sure how to input the x and where to input the x so just decided to draw three lines for the triangle.

I just need help as to how and where I would input the x into the line or even polygon function. Like for the circle one would simply put it first but how would it be for a line and/or polygon function?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use pygame.draw.aalines() instead.

Give it a list of points forming the triangle.

Your problem here is:

1. X is increasing indefinitely
2. It increases too fast.

If you want to make this nice, make a object called Fish, with a method move, which wil move the fish. This way you will have clean code and minimal confusion.

You must remove the old fish from the window, then draw the new one on the new position. That's why you should keep the fish in its own object.

Choose one point of the fish that will act as an universal position indicator. E.g. a nose or centre of the mass, or something. Then you just change that pos and your move method adjusts all other coordinates accordingly.

EDIT:

This is an example. I didn't try it, just put it together to show you how it is done.

I hope this will make it clearer. You see, I draw the fish once on itsown surface, then I move this surface around.

As you move the mouse, the fish will be moved.

It may be slow, and flickery, and stuff. This code has some problem as yours.

The new fish should be drawn every 4 pixels, not each one.

As fish is in an object you can have multiple fishes of different sizes.

Each fish keeps portion of a screen that replaces in an origsurf attribute.

Before it moves, it returns the screen in previous position.

So your fishes can overlap on the screen.

To make all work smooth, you will have to do some more work.

For example, there are no safeguards against going over display bounds.

As I said, it is an example on how it is done, not a full code.

```
class Fish:
    def __init__ (self, pos=(0, 0), size=(60, 40), bgcolour=(255, 255, 255)):
        self.pos = pos; self.size = size
        # Use a little surface and draw your fish in it:
        self.surf = surf = pygame.Surface(size)
        surf.fill(bgcolour)
        # Draw something:
        pygame.draw.aalines(surf, (0, 0, 0), 1, [(0, 0), (0, size[1]), (size[0], size[1]/2)]) # Triangle
        # Save how screen looks where fish will be:
        self.origsurf = Surface(size)
        sub = screen.subsurface((pos, size))
        self.origsurf.blit(sub)
        # Show the fish:
        screen.blit(surf, pos)
        pygame.display.flip()

    def move (self, newpos):
        # Remove the fish from old position
        screen.blit(self.origsurf, self.pos)
        # Save how screen looks where fish will be:
        self.origsurf = Surface(self.size)
        sub = screen.subsurface((newpos, self.size))
        self.origsurf.blit(sub)
        # Then show the fish on new location:
        screen.blit(self.surf, newpos)
        self.pos = newpos
        pygame.display.flip()

screen = pygame.display.set_mode()
fish = Fish()
FPS=100
fpsClock=pygame.time.Clock()
while True:
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type=="QUIT":
            pygame.quit()
            sys.exit()
        elif event.type==pygame.MOUSEMOTION:
            fish.move(event.pos)
    fpsClock.tick(FPS)
```

Comment: Ah I see, thank you albeit I am still slightly confused as to how I would do this.

Comment: @mars : See my edit. It should clarify some things. I didn't draw the whole fish. Just a triangle to show you how it is done.